# Add background color when click a button vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, button, vue-component, background-color

I'm building an app with VUE JS, using different components.

In one of them, I have a button that I would like that change the color when I click on it. This button is choosing different items from a table, so when I press that button I want that the background of that button change to red for example to know which ones I have clicked.

```
<template>
  <button class="mdc-icon-button material-icons"  @click="doMultiple">delete_outline</button>  
</template>
```

This is the button. How can I add there the style when button be clicked?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please go through Vue class and style bindings. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: You can do this by adding a class conditionally on click of that button.
<button class="mdc-icon-button material-icons" :class="{ bg-red: clicked }">clickme</button>

clicked value will be initially false and set it to true on click.

Comment: @Ramki Thanks, but I have tried what you said and it returns me an error on :class because it says that it require an attribute value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional binding to dynamically add a class to an element.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    deleteClicked: false
  },
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      this.deleteClicked = true;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div :class="{ red : deleteClicked }">
    Item
    <button @click="onClick">
      Delete
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, not exactly what I was looking for but that can help me. Thanks Pierre!!

Comment: And what about the original class? How do you preserve it in the element?

Comment: @rjurney You can have both static classes and dynamic classes `<div class="static" :class="{ dynamic : true }">`

https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax

Answer (score 1):

```
Call the css class with either of the option

.mdc-icon-button material-icons:active{
    background:red;
}
OR

.mdc-icon-button material-icons:focus{
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of linking js variables to vue js with watch method. This is immediate and will change as you drag the cursor along the color picker. Check the code snippet below. CSS is also required.

```js
let vue = new Vue({
  el: "#view",
  data: {
    bg: "#FFFFFF",
    color: "#000000",
  },
  watch: {
    bg: css_variable_watcher("--bg"),
    color: css_variable_watcher("--color"),
  },
});
//Watcher for CSS
function css_variable_watcher(name, suffix = "") {
  return {
    immediate: true,
    handler(new_value, old_value) {
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty(name, new_value + suffix);
    },
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: var(--bg);
  color: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="view">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <input type="color" v-model="bg">
    <input type="color" v-model="color">
    <button type="button" v-on:click="[color, bg] = [bg, color]">Swap Text and Background Color</button>
    <p>Hello. I am a Paragraph. Select the first input to change bg color and second input to change text color.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```